# Android app freezing after few days

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm developing an app used basically as kiosk app. It has a webview in which premade page is displayed.

The app is supposed to be running indefinitelly but unfortunately, when I test it, after a few days it freezes and stops to respond. Last time this took 6 days.

Is it possible there is a problem in current implementation of the app, or are android apps(or webviews) not designed for running such a long time?

Comment: Is it leaking memory?  Have you attached a debugger to see if it's hanging?

Comment: I came to android development from pure java background and I thought such problems do not occure thanks to garbage collector. What can cause memory leaks on android?

Comment: Check out these docs: http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Comment: It's also possible for native (aka C++) code in a library to leak memory.

Comment: I'll check the link. No native code is used in the app. Do you think it is sane to expect android app to run that long with no problems?

Comment: As long as there are no leaks, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a memory leak, there are plenty of posts around about how to avoid leaks - http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

also, check out the [leak canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)   library, it will notify you when get a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.